# Large json to .csv

Tags: json, r, validation, twitter

I have two .json files of twitter data that are 2.9 GB that I need to convert into either .csv or .xml for further processing.

I manged to get a some of the data to open in Firefox in text form and then paste it in an online .json viewer to at least see what it looks like but I'm not sure if that looks typical as I've never worked with .json before?

[image: Example block of twitter .json]

I tried to open the file in eclipse with a .json extension but it crashed.

So my idea now is to use R and to convert to a excel like file so I can work with it but I'm not sure how to go about that. So far I have this:

```
library(rjson)
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

json_file <- "C:\\Users\\Jesse\\Desktop\\research\\Twitter\\Louisiana Flood         2016\\lou.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(file =json_file, method = "C", unexpected.escape =  "error" )

write.xlsx(json_data, "C:\\Users\\Jesse\\Desktop\\research\\Twitter\\Louisiana Flood 2016\\data.xlsx")
```

So, my question is. Is this a good approach or how can I convert these files into an excel?

Edit:spelling

Comment: Did you mean .csv rather than .cvs?  Also what further processing do you wan to do?

Comment: Oh! yes I did thank you. Edited. 

Well after I get it into a .csv I intend to load it into SPSS to clean it up and then into ArcGIS to plot the geolocation of the data.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237345/import-json-in-excel

Comment: Doesn't work for me  but thanks.

Comment: "convert to Excel so I can work with it",  "load into SPSS to clean it up" - once you've got it in R you will be able to do all your cleaning and manipulation processes. I don't see a need to move it into Excel or SPSS

Comment: " I'm not sure if that looks typical" - yes, it's typical. JSON is a standard, and is designed to store nested lists/arrays and objects. It may not easily convert to a 'standard' table like you're used to with Excel.

Comment: Im sure you are correct that it can be done in R but I dont know R that well so it is easier for me at this moment to do it that way.

Comment: You're going about it in such a roundabout manner. I'll load it into R using `rjson` or `jsonlite`,  flatten the dataframe if needed, then use one of the mapping packages like `rMaps`

Comment: Ok. I think you may need to change your question. If your `fromJSON` is working, what you're actually asking is 'how do I convert this object to a flat `data.frame`'. In which case your can simplify your question as most of it is irrelevant.

Comment: @waterling I believe you as I dont know what I am doing. Can you point me in the direction of some explicit instructions as I dont know what you said means. Thank you.

Comment: Like idk what flatten data frame means.

Comment: `data.frame` is one of the basic data structures in `R`. I suggest you look up some 'introduction to R' tutorials.

Comment: Okay. I can take it form here. Thanks for your input.